# SONY Lifelog Api: SSL Handshake failure

Tags: python, ssl, sony, sony-lifelog-api

I get an SSL handshake failure while trying to reach `platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com:443` with either python (with `requests` library) or `openssl`.

Here are the output I get from **openssl**

**ssl3**:

```
$ >openssl s_client -connect platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com:443 -ssl3 -state 
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:failed in SSLv3 read server hello A
3073824444:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1262:SSL alert number 40
3073824444:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
  Protocol  : SSLv3
  Cipher    : 0000
  Session-ID: 
  Session-ID-ctx: 
  Master-Key: 
  Key-Arg   : None
  PSK identity: None
  PSK identity hint: None
  SRP username: None
  Start Time: 1464110874
  Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
  Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

**tlsv1.1**:

```
$>openssl s_client -connect platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com:443 -tls1_1
CONNECTED(00000003)
3074041532:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert    handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1262:SSL alert number 40
3074041532:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
  Protocol  : TLSv1.1
  Cipher    : 0000
  Session-ID: 
  Session-ID-ctx: 
  Master-Key: 
  Key-Arg   : None
  PSK identity: None
  PSK identity hint: None
  SRP username: None
  Start Time: 1464110950
   Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
  Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

**tlsv1.2**:

```
$>openssl s_client -connect platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com:443 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
3074123452:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1262:SSL alert number 40
3074123452:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
   Protocol  : TLSv1.2
  Cipher    : 0000
  Session-ID: 
  Session-ID-ctx: 
  Master-Key: 
  Key-Arg   : None
  PSK identity: None
  PSK identity hint: None
  SRP username: None
  Start Time: 1464110938
  Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
  Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Do I need a client certificat or anything else?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have not used openssl that much, but you will have to run the standard oath 2.0 process to start retrieving data. For instance, starting with this call: https://platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com/oauth/2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&scope=lifelog.profile.read+lifelog.activities.read+lifelog.locations.read. Have you registered for a client I'd and secret? You can read more about the process here: https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `google-oauth-java-client` from https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client to get data regularly from lifelog API. No special care was needed for certificates. Previous to Android client, I tested all my logic with a ARC (a Chrome's rest client ), also did some tests with `curl`, once I got the Bearer like this (you need to get your Authorization value following Lifelog API docs):

```
curl 'https://platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com/v1/users/me/activities' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer AuyKFAzQar5xhgRHhHKlboApaRKH' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Cookie: BLABLA' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact I did find my way out of this by installing `requests`with additional security packages (`pip install requests[seccurity]`). By doing so, it worked like a charm (better handling of certificates issues).